# Change Python filesystem encoding

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

How can one change Python's filesystem encoding (returned by `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`)? 
My goal is to make `os.listdir` return Unicode names when fed a Unicode path, however this only works if the filesystem encoding is also Unicode.

This filesystem encoding is used to encode `os.listdir(unicodestring)` output, and by default (if no `LC_*` env vars are specified) it is ASCII.

I tried to inject `LC_ALL` through `os.putenv`, `os.environ`, `locale.setlocale` to no avail; filesystem encoding doesn't change. Reloading `os` and `sys` modules afterwards doesn't help either.

Example with LC_ALL specified:

```
$ env -i LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 python -c "import os; print os.listdir(u'.');"
[u'\u0435\u0449\u0433\u0441\u0440']
```

Example with empty environment:

```
$ env -i python -c "import os; print os.listdir(u'.');" 
['\xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd0\xb3\xd1\x81\xd1\x80']
```

A possible solution would be to include environment variable in a wrapper startup script, however I would prefer a way to that from inside Python.

Comment: the filesystem encoding is set by the operating system...

Comment: @MattDMo on modern Linux, it's safe to assume that it's UTF8. The point is that without environment vars, Python fails to determine actual filesystem encoding and defaults to ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't trust that the OS is configured properly via the `LC_ALL` variable, then you can do the encoding/decoding yourself:

```
import os
def listdir(dirpath):
    if isinstance(dirpath,unicode):
        dirpath = dirpath.encode('utf8')
    return [p.decode('utf8') for p in os.listdir(dirpath)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have ended up monkey-patching os.listdir in similar manner